# Equality of definitions of Lower Semicontinuity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

I would like to show the equality (i.e. iff) of the following definitions of lower semicontinuity **without** the use of **liminf**.

**Definition:** Lower Semicontinuous

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a [normed vector space](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/normed-linear-spaces) with a topology $\tau(X)$ [induced by said norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1455821). A function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *lower semicontinuous* if

1. $\forall(x_{0}\in X, \epsilon > 0)~~\exists ~ \delta>0~$ s.t. $\forall x\in X~~||x_{0}-x||<\delta \implies f(x_{0})-f(x) < \epsilon$
2. $\{x\in X:f(x) \leq \alpha \}$ is closed in X,$~$ i.e. $\{x\in X:f(x) \leq \alpha \}^{~c} \in\tau(X)$,  $~\forall\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

$~$

Here are similar questions and useful links:

- [closed epigraphs equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467441/closed-epigraphs-equivalence)
- [Show the iff statement of lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280479/show-the-iff-statement-of-lower-semicontinuous)
- https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semicontinuous_function
- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Lower_Semicontinuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the condition 1 holds true, and let $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. If $x_0\in f^{-1}((\alpha, +\infty))$, then let $\varepsilon =f(x_0)-\alpha$. By hypothesis, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>f(x_0)-\varepsilon=\alpha$ whenever $\lVert x-x_0\rVert<\delta$. Equivalently, the ball of radius $\delta>0$ centered at $x_0$ lies in $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty))$. Since this is true for all $x_0\in f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty))$, we conclude that $f^{-1}(\alpha,+\infty)$ is open, that is, $f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha])$ is closed. Thus the condition 2 holds true.

Conversely, suppose that the condition 2 holds true, and let $x_0\in X$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, the set $f^{-1}((-\infty,f(x_0)-\varepsilon])$ is closed, and thus its complement $f^{-1}((f(x_0)-\varepsilon,\infty))$ is open. Because $x_0\in f^{-1}((f(x_0)-\varepsilon,\infty))$, this means that there is some $\delta>0$ such that the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x_0$ lies in $f^{-1}((f(x_0)-\varepsilon,\infty))$. This $\delta $ satisfies the requirement in the condition 1.

---

The proof is very, very similar to the proof that continuity of a function is equivalent to continuity at all points in the domain. In fact, $X$ need not be a normed vector space, but any metric space.

Comment: In the first paragraph, I think you meant $f(x) > f(x_{0}) - \varepsilon$ instead of $f(x) > f(x_{0}) + \varepsilon$...

Comment: @Griffy Yes, you're right. Thank you for pointing it out.